# Como desativar valor padrão no kendo dropdownlist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

Tenho um kendo grid e estou criando um template para edição dos dados apresentados na grid, mas estou com problemas no código abaixo...

Este é parte do código do meu template:

```
<script id="popup_editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">

<div class="k-edit-label">
   <label for="Sexo">Sexo</label>
</div>

<input name="Sexo"
   data-bind="value:Sexo"
   data-value-field="sexoValue"
   data-text-field="sexoName"
   data-source="sexoDropDownDataSource"
   data-role="dropdownlist" />

</script>
```

Este é meu script para preencher o `dropdownlist` com os dados necessários:

```
sexoDropDownDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                autoBind: false,
                dataTextField: "sexoName",
                dataValueField: "sexoValue",
                data: [
                    { sexoName: "Masculino", sexoValue: "M" },
                    { sexoName: "Feminino", sexoValue: "F" }
                ]
            });
```

Como podem ver está tudo certo, e o código está funcionando perfeitamente trazendo o valor que está na grid, mas o problema é que mesmo com o `autoBind` recebendo o valor `false` o `dropdownlist` está vindo com a primeira opção sempre selecionada (no caso `masculino`), ou seja, quando os dados de uma pessoa do sexo `feminino` é editado, o `dropdownlist` mostra como padrão o valor que veio da grid (`feminino`), mas quando é expandido é exibido os dois valores selecionados. Como posso resolver isso?

Vejam do que estou falando:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Vasculhei a [documentação](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist) e não consegui encontrar nada sobre como desativar isto, entretanto, como alternativa, você pode setar um valor padrão usando a propriedade `value`, veja [este exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/dmm02to6/).

Comment: Pois é meu amigo, muito obrigado pelo empenho em me ajudar, eu também ainda não encontrei nada. O problema é que no meu caso o `kendoDropDownList` é criado dentro do `x-kendo-template` e não posso criar um objeto desse tipo em javascript para ser colocado lá, apenas o `DataSource`. Estou estudando um pouco desse `x-kendo-template`, não é possível que não exista uma propriedade que dê pra fazer isso.

Comment: Outra coisa, é que na verdade eu não gostaria de vir com um valor padrão marcado, mas ao contrário, eu gostaria que apenas o valor que está na grid viesse marcada.

Comment: Alguma chance de você conseguir reproduzir isso numa demo?

Answer (score -1):

Tente utilizar o evento `dataBound` no seu dropdownlist para deixar selecionado o valor que vem do grid. Talvez nesse link poderá lhe ajudar:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937194/kendo-dropdownlist-default-item-binding-with-kendo-grid

Exemplo:

```
var sexoDataDropDown = $("#sexoDropDownDataSource").data("kendoDropDownList");
sexoDataDropDown.value(Masculino);
```

Comment: Bem, acho que não expliquei direito a questão... Preciso que o DropDown não venha com valor selecionado, apenas o que veio da Grid. O problema é que está vindo o valor feminino da grid, mas o DropDown sempre deixa selecionado o primeiro elemento dele que no caso é masculino, então acaba ficando como na imagem..

Comment: então use o evento OnDataBinding para deixar somente o valor que não está selecionado com o background branco (#ffffff), dê uma olhada:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609344/how-to-format-individual-dropdownlist-items-color-etc-during-ondatabinding-e